# Use Local Time zone in Web Lotus Notes Application

Tags: web, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus-formula

Is there a way to make the time (local) being used by the web based lotus notes application. I noticed that in notes client that basically it always uses the right time of the local machine so it doesn't confuse the users. Wherever he/she is in the world.

The problem is happening in the web, it uses the server machine time thus confusing the user. For example a user created a new document the time it would display or use in the web is the server machine. How can I use or convert it to local machine or local time zone.

The formula I used is just `@Now`, I already looked in the internet for solution but I did not find what I need or maybe didn't noticed them so if you have links please share it here and if you know how then do guide me. I saw a solution but it's not efficient, it requires changing the web browser options thus it requires to be set up in every computer. I would like to implement it in codes thus the users would not do anything.

Is there a formula in getting the timezone of the local machine? `@GetCurrentTimeZone` which still gets the timezone of the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Javascript in the browser to detect the local timezone and adjust the time accordingly.

Updated:
Take a look at this blog entry: http://blog.texasswede.com/replace-images-on-web-page-using-jquery/

I would suggest that you do something similar. Put a span around the time (make sure you have the time as GMT/UTC) with a specific class that makes it easy for you to get all the instances of a time you need to change. You want the HTML to look something like this:

```
<span class="GMTtime">7/8/2014 1:23:45 PM UTC</span>
```

Then you write some Javascript/jQuery code that will execute after the page is loaded (like in the example linked above). Something like this (not tested):

```
$(".GMTtime").each( function() {
    var gmttime = $(this).html(); // Get GMT time value
    var d = new Date(gmttime); // Create date object
    // Get local time and remove TZ offset at end
    var localtime = d.toString().replace(/GMT.*/g,""); 
    $(this).html(localtime);      // Replace GMT value with local value in HTML
});
```

Comment: Hi Karl, Can you give me a link regarding this kind of functionality. I'll look and research now into it but if I didn't updated this question. Please do guide and help me. I am not really good or familiar with javascript but I know a little about it such as the basic functionality. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you are going to develop web applications, you should learn Javascript (in addition to HTML and CSS), at least if you want some more advanced functionality and a web application that looks good.

Comment: Hi Karl, I have another follow up question. Is it possible to directly do it in a view that is being used or displayed in web? I think using javascript would require me to saved those values right? I know that with javascript it is possible but are there no other ways? If no, then can you share on how are you planning to implement it in the shortest way, I would like to just display it in the view and no need to store/save the right values.

Comment: Is there a formula in getting the timezone of the local machine? @GetCurrentTimeZone which still gets the timezone of the server.

Comment: No, for web applications, any formulas are executed on the server before/when the HTML is generated. How could the server know the time zone of the web browser? Use the Javascript function I linked to above.

Comment: I updated the answer above with more details and some code for you to try.

Comment: Hi Karl, Thanks for the information regarding the web applications. I have a lot to learn. Regarding your updated answer, I totally get that part actually I was thinking that way too, but I am confused on how to apply it in a view. I get it that when I open a page or a form I can do what you shared since that's the usual way right? What I am not sure is for a view, I though of creating a form template for the view but still I can't accomplish it. I reviewed the events in the view but not sure how to update the column value. I hope you get what I meant.. Thanks a lot Karl. I am really grateful.

Comment: Create a "$$ViewTemplate for ..." form- Put your HTML and Javascript there. The trick with creating what we call "classic domino web applications" is to understand the different components and how Domino render HTML, and then change the resulting output by making changes in settings, adding fields, computed text and pass-though HTML to get the desired output.

Comment: Hi Karl, regarding the "$$ViewTemplate..." is what I meant above for creating a form for the view. Anyways I'll explore more today since I haven't focused on this item for a while yet since there are a lot of list that I need to finish. Thanks for helping out, will select your answer once I am able to apply it and also forgive me for asking to basic questions thanks.